# cordova requirements issue , android target not installed

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, cordova-plugins

I am trying to install Cordova on windows 7. 
I am following this tutorial : 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_first_application.htm

while I run **cordova requirements**, it says android target is not intalled 
and set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable

```
I:\CordovaProject\hello>cordova requirements
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the 
default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: installed
Error: Some of requirements check failed

I:\CordovaProject\hello>echo %ANDROID_HOME%
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

as you can see in the image 1, when I echo ANDROID_HOME it is set to proper location. I am not able to resolve this error. kindly help me with this

path has these : %ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

I have downloaded android-25 in android studio

and project properties file has android target set to : android-25 both in 
I:\CordovaProject\hello\platforms\android\CordovaLib\project.properties
I:\CordovaProject\hello\platforms\android\project.properties

and when i run **cordova build android** i get following error

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 31.807 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
 > Could not download uast.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-
 intellij:uast:145.597.3)
  > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ex
 ternal/com-intellij/uast/145.597.3/uast-145.597.3.jar'.
     > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external
  /com-intellij/uast/145.597.3/uast-145.597.3.jar'.
        > akamai.bintray.com

  * Try:
   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -
   -debug   option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 9):

**For SDK 21 ("android-21")**

```
$ cordova platform remove android
$ cordova platform add android@3.7.1
```

**For SDK 22 (Android 4.1.1, "android-22")**

```
$ cordova platform remove android
$ cordova platform add android@4.1.1
```

Comment: its `platform` singular, not plural.

Answer (score 7):

I found the same issue and fix it!

Its related to Java path in `JAVA_HOME` and `Path` Variable should contain the same path with Android Studio (JRE folder). You may found this info in Android Studio, SDK Location.

After Change my `Path` and `JAVA_HOME` variable (go to control panel, system and security, system, environment variable) update `Path` and `JAVA_HOME` variable to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`.

More detail...
`JAVA_HOME` contains `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`
and `Path` contains `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin`

checking requirements all good !

cordova requirements

Comment: Totally different from http://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-windows.html#Introduction. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the build target specified in the Manifest and then cross check if you have the same target sdk installed using sdk manager in android-studio.

**Note:**
The line you should be looking for will be:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Comment: This file is located in `platforms\android\CordovaLib\AndroidManifest.xml` correct ?

Answer (score 2):

An easy and quick answer:

if your Env variables are not set correctly you will see any possible error, **most errors will be solved** if you set (**correctly**) :

(WARNING: I assume that you already have JAVA JDK set)

```
 ANDROID_HOME: C:\Users\marwe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

 ANDROID_SDK_ROOT: C:\Users\marwe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

You can change the path according to your machine, you can find the Android SDK path by opening Android Studio like shown in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may also try As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097394/2642351 try installing JDK version less than 9, like JDK8

Answer (score 0):

**Linux (Xubuntu)**:
I have android-studio installed in */opt/google/android-studio*; 
but the sdk folder is trully installed in */home/{computerName}/Android/Sdk*;
**Error in Android target install was a PATH problem** 
Remove the misleading PATH and reinserting the correct one was the solution:
at the end of file in  ***.bashrc*** (*/home/{computerName}/.bashrc*)

```
PATH=$(REMOVE_PART="/opt/google/android-sdk/" sh -c 'echo ":$PATH:" | sed "s@:$REMOVE_PART:@:@g;s@^:\(.*\):\$@\1@"')
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/home/{computerName}/Android/Sdk"
export ANDROID_HOME= "/home/{computerName}/Android/Sdk"
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

***{computerName}*** to be substituted with your computer name. 
checked if there was any previous *export* statements that would conflict; 
closed the terminal and reopened it.
called *env* in terminal:

```
env
```

to check if the .bashrc was correctly loaded; 
after confirmation, re-runned cordova requirements;

```
cordova requirements
```

this fix in the path also solved the issue of "not finding platform tools" error in cordova run command.

Answer (score 0):

OpenJDK 8 fixed this for me on Windows 11.

```
C:\Users\16515\Desktop\prj\cordova\hello>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_352-352"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_352-352-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.352-b08, mixed mode)

C:\Users\16515\Desktop\prj\cordova\hello>cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-31,android-30,android-29,android-28,android-27,android-26
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\gradle-7.5.1\bin\gradle.BAT
```