# cordova requirements error "Android target: not installed"

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

Using cordova on WINDOWS 10 I'm not able to build project.

When I tried `cordova requirements` it shows me `Android target: not installed`.

I tried all possible solutions over internet and SO, however, none worked for me. Probably this is related to the latest version of cordova v 8.0.0.

I tried the following which did NOT work:
 1. overwriting tools folder from cordova CLI in my `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` folder.
 2. `cordova platform remove android` and then `cordova platform add android@7.0.0`
 3. Uninstalling and reinstalling all SDKs in Android Studio.
 4. `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />`
 5. Updated `config.xml` file with

```
<platform name="android">

  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/> 
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26"/>

  <!--other line code -->

</platform>
```

6. Installed all SDK from SDK manager in Android Studio from 16 to 27.

Following is the log after firing the requirements command:

```
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.parseSdk(AvdManagerCli.java:328)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:204)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:195)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 6 more
Gradle: installed
```

Please suggest a solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Is your ANDROID_PATH env variable set ?

Comment: ANDROID_HOME is set to the path to the SDK but I've not set ANDROID_PATH. What should it point to?

Comment: Also, I've updated my question with the log that I get after I run the requirements command

Comment: My bad, wanted to say ANDROID_HOME.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I fixed it! I downgraded my JDK to version 8.172. Seems like JDK version above 8 is not supported by Android SDK. Then, update your JAVA_HOME path in the Environment Variables to point to the new JDK folder path. If you are using Mac or *nix boxes, you may also try jenv as well (I could not try jenv, but let me know if it did work for you)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I would have never thought to downgrade jdk versions

Comment: Why was this so hard?!? I just spent 2 hours troubleshooting this on macOS Mojave. Following your advice, I found an archived JDK version named `jdk-8u172-macosx-x64.dmg` on Oracle's website, installed that, and voila, `cordova requirements` are satisfied!